# Ayuda con select2 multiple

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, select2

tengo un formulario de reservaciones, en el cual me pidieron que un cliente pueda hacer varias reservaciones en una factura,pensé en utilizar select2 con la opción multiple para agregar varias habitaciones de forma fácil y amigable, pero, siempre hay un pero, cuando añado más de 1 habitación siempre retorna los datos del primer valor seleccionado y no suma suma la cantidad total de todas las habitaciones seleccionadas.

Código:

```
<select class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Seleccionar una o varias habitaciones" name="room" id="rooms">
    @foreach($rooms as $key => $room)
        <option value="{{$room->id}}">{{$room->identificador}} - {{ $room->r_roms_precios[0]->r_precio->r_categoria->categoria }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>      

        $('#rooms').change(function(){
            $('#tipoCliente').empty();
            var idRoom = $(this).val();
            var url ="{{ url('reservaciones/mostrarCategoria') }}/"+idRoom;

            console.log(idRoom);
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(e) {
                    console.log(e);
                    $.each(e.tipos, function(index, el) {

                    if (e.Rom.booking && el.tipo_reservacion == 'Booking'){
                        var opcion = '<option value="'+ el.id +'">Booking</option>';
                        mostrarPrecio(e.roomsPrecio[0].r_precio.categoria_id);
                    }

                    if (e.Rom.trivago && el.tipo_reservacion == 'Trivago'){
                        var opcion = '<option value="'+ el.id +'">Trivago</option>';
                         mostrarPrecio(e.roomsPrecio[0].r_precio.categoria_id);
                    }

                    if (e.Rom.nacional && el.tipo_reservacion == 'Nacional'){
                        var opcion = '<option value="'+ el.id +'">Nacional</option>';
                         mostrarPrecio(e.roomsPrecio[0].r_precio.categoria_id);
                    }

                    $('#tipoCliente').append( opcion );
                    });

                    $("#tipoCliente").prepend("<option value='' selected='selected'></option>");

                    $('#tipoCategoria').html(e.roomsPrecio[0].r_precio.r_categoria.categoria);
                }
            })
        })
```

Controlador:

```
public function mostrarCategoria($id)
{
    $rom         = Rom::find($id);
    $tipos       = Tipo::all();

    $roomsPrecio = RomsPrecio::where('rom_id', $id)->get();

    foreach ($roomsPrecio as $key => $roomsPrecios) {
      $roomsPrecios->r_precio->r_categoria;
    }

    return response()->json(['roomsPrecio' => $roomsPrecio, 'Rom' => $rom, 'tipos' => $tipos], 200);
}
```

Demostración:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No suma las habitaciones seleccionadas:

[image: Suma]

Dónde dice 23.12 tiene que haber 44,62

Comment: El error lo tienes el la variable `url`. Por lo que he visto cuando haces el value de `idRoom` generas un array por lo que tiene más de 1 valor, y directamente lo estas poniendo en la variable `url` por lo que la url sería `http://..../10,25` en vez de 10 y 25. Para solucionarlo tendrías que hacer un for con el tamaño del array y generar el contenido. He supuesto que ese es tu problema, aunque no lo he probado

Comment: @matahombres, si ese es mi problema, que genera /10,25 y siempre retorna los datos del primer valor seleccionado que en este caso es el 10, algún ejemplo de como lo pueda hacer?

Answer (score 0):

**Explicación:** Al tener varios valores el idRoom genera un array, por lo que tendrás que recorrer ese array y ejecutar el codigo tantas veces sea el tamaño del array. Ej:

```
       var idRoom = $(this).val();
       for(i=0;i<idRoom.length();i++){
          var url ="{{ url('reservaciones/mostrarCategoria') }}/"+idRoom[i];

          console.log(idRoom);
          $.ajax({
              url: url,
              type: 'GET',
              success: function(e) {
                    .....
              }
          });
        }
```

Comment: Gracias por comentar, por lo que puedo ver cada vez que lo recorre seguira añadiendo los id en forma de array pero seguira haciendo lo mismo.

Comment: Entonces me dices que es un string y no devuelve un array? Me refiero, en el caso de que pusiera una `,` simplemente en vez de crear un array. Si es así comentamelo y edito el código